# Add a global event listener which always listens for server calls using Jquery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do I set up a global event listener which keeps on listening for server calls. These server calls will be requests for setting up a session with another user. The best example I can give to put my point through to you is, its like skype, whenever anyone logs in, that user has an eventlistener which listens for any calls which other users may want to make to this user. So could I use something like the live or the delegate function in jquery, or do you have some other suggestions. I would highly appreciate it if you could direct me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want to execute a function whenever an Ajax call is made?

Comment: I dont think so. This app is going to be a mobile application. I need it to listen for any changes that the server may relay to it. Is that even possible using jquery/js

Comment: Open a websocket connection to your server from your web page.  Then, your server can send you notifications over that websocket when an event occurs.  FYI, this has nothing to do with jQuery event handling.

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense, let me look into this. Yaa and I am sorry about the use of jQuery, i had no clue about websockets.

Comment: So I looked into this and I looked at some code, but noticed that the client is suppose to send a msg first and then the server responds, but what I need the server to send a msg anytime he wants and the client is always ready to receive that msg.

Comment: So I think I am actually looking for a PHP push notification server.

Answer (score 3):

After loads of research, this is what I found and works perfectly:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

HTML5 rocks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I also found an alternative ans, where I use the workers and open a websocket with them. I dont know how scalable this soln this, but still.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/